# "was will was" - Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> As I grew it was interesting to discover how much of what I had thought was will was affected by the flesh.

Is this grammatically correct?  I am confused about the part that **was will was** Is this correct? I think it should be like this:

> ...how much of what I had thought was affected...

Comment: It was interesting to discover how much of what I had thought to be "free will" was actually affected by the demands of the body. To make this a little clearer, the author could have written *was **the** will*, or as I have done in the paraphrase, "free will".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is confusing, but it is grammatically correct.  I think the key to understanding it is that [**will** in this sentence is a noun](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/will_2); it is not the same as *will* in "I will go to the store".  *Will* as a noun means something like

> [someone’s determination to do what is necessary to achieve what they want](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/will_2)

So the sentence basically reads

> ...much of what I had thought was **X** was **Y**

and X here is *will*, meaning "determination".

Comment: Thanks. Correct me if i wrong. how much of K was affected by flesh 
K = What I had though was will